# picture element responsive images not working with angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, picturefill, picture-element

The picture element as

```
 <picture>
     <source  media="(max-width: 768px)" srcset="../assets/image1.png">
     <source  media="(min-width: 769px)" srcset="../assets/image2.png">
     <source  src="../assets/image3.png">
 </picture>
```

does not work in Angular 4
It selects the first source for all viewport widths, which in the above example is image1.png

Any solutions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular has nothing to do with this. The browser interprets the `<picture>` code alone.

Anyway, the main issue with your code is that it lacks the mandatory `<img>` element.

Also, the third `<source>` is useless, the viewport will be either `max-width: 768px` or `min-width: 769px`, it can't be another value.

Comment: great, glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 1048px)" [srcset]="bannerMobOne" />
  <img [src]="bannerOne" alt="" />
</picture>
```

(or)

```
<picture>
  <source media="(max-width: 1048px)" srcset="assets/images/landing/Banner01.jpg" />
  <img src="assets/images/landing/Banner01.jpg" alt="" />
</picture>
```